# Check for consecutive years of giving in R

Tags: r, csv, subset

I work at a non-profit organization, and somebody wants a list of people who have given $100 or more in a 5-year span.  The span can be anywhere, as long as they have given in 5 consecutive years.  I have both Python and R on the computer.  R seems like it would be better for this, but I'm not very familiar with it.

I've imported a csv file of every gift to the organization and who gave it.

Here is an example line from the csv file.

- Gf_Gift_ID: 1620192
- Gf_Date: 1/31/2005
- Gf_Amount: 25.00
- Gf_CnBio_ID: 512994

I couldn't get it to format correctly on here.  The first part is the headers.

I need to be able to see if user 512994 has given 100 or more in, for example, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, and 2010 (five consecutive years).

So far I have this in the R script:

```
gifts <- read.csv("---------")
donors <- gifts["Gf_CnBio_ID"]
donors <- unique(donors)
```

I keep trying to figure out how to make a smaller dataframe that is a subset of gifts, by going one at a time through donors to subset gifts, and then I'd check to see how many years in a row that person has given.  I keep getting errors the different ways I've tried it.

Thanks in advance.   Most of my background is in Java so this language is not what I'm used to.

ADDITION:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(lubridate)
> 
> set.seed(999)
> 
> gifts <- read.csv("---.CSV", header = TRUE, sep = ",", )
> donors <- gifts["Donor_ID"]
> donors <- unique(donors)
> 
> gifts %>%
+   mutate(gift_year = year(gifts["Gift_Date"])) %>% # extract year
+   group_by(gifts["Donor_ID"], gift_year) %>% 
+   summarise(year_gift = sum(gifts["Gift_Amount"])) %>% # total gift per donor/year
+   filter(year_gift >= 100) %>% 
+   group_by(bio_id) %>% 
+   mutate(diff = gift_year - lag(gift_year), rle = rep( rle(diff)$lengths, rle(diff)$lengths)) %>% 
+   filter(rle >= 5) %>% 
+   distinct(bio_id)
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

I keep getting that error output when trying to run the supplied solution.  I made a Python program to reformat the dates to yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 format and I still get the error, so it's not from the date format.  I don't know what's causing it.  Here's the  first 50 rows.

```
> dput(shortExport)
structure(list(Gift_ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1620192L, 1630540L, 1661287L, 1670815L, 1702338L, 
1710859L, 1747572L, 1781100L, 1811188L, 1829753L, 1854499L, 1860830L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1361280L, 1246941L, 1355077L, 1243748L, 1243748L, 1518414L
), Gift_Date = structure(c(2L, 23L, 32L, 10L, 17L, 19L, 33L, 
44L, 45L, 11L, 27L, 30L, 47L, 3L, 26L, 9L, 18L, 31L, 37L, 22L, 
28L, 16L, 25L, 34L, 39L, 21L, 42L, 1L, 29L, 35L, 43L, 6L, 13L, 
4L, 5L, 38L, 41L, 46L, 15L, 24L, 40L, 2L, 12L, 20L, 14L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 36L), .Label = c("1/29/2010 0:00", "1/30/2014 0:00", 
"1/31/2005 0:00", "1/31/2012 0:00", "1/31/2013 0:00", "10/11/2011 0:00", 
"10/18/2000 0:00", "10/27/1998 0:00", "10/31/2005 0:00", "10/31/2011 0:00", 
"10/31/2012 0:00", "11/1/2011 0:00", "11/11/2011 0:00", "11/18/1998 0:00", 
"11/27/2013 0:00", "11/30/2007 0:00", "11/30/2011 0:00", "12/30/2005 0:00", 
"12/30/2011 0:00", "12/6/2000 0:00", "2/27/2009 0:00", "2/28/2007 0:00", 
"2/28/2011 0:00", "2/28/2014 0:00", "2/29/2008 0:00", "3/31/2005 0:00", 
"3/31/2013 0:00", "4/30/2007 0:00", "4/30/2010 0:00", "4/30/2013 0:00", 
"5/31/2006 0:00", "5/31/2011 0:00", "6/29/2012 0:00", "6/30/2008 0:00", 
"6/30/2011 0:00", "7/18/2003 0:00", "7/31/2006 0:00", "7/31/2013 0:00", 
"8/29/2008 0:00", "8/29/2014 0:00", "8/30/2013 0:00", "8/31/2009 0:00", 
"8/31/2011 0:00", "8/31/2012 0:00", "9/28/2012 0:00", "9/30/2013 0:00", 
"9/30/2014 0:00"), class = "factor"), Gift_Amount = c(25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
50L, 10L, 10L, 100L, 100L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 100L, 250L, 50L, 30L, 25L, 50L, 50L, 50L), Donor_ID = c(677556L, 
521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 
521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 521512L, 512994L, 512994L, 
512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 
512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 
512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 
512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 512994L, 679277L, 406147L, 
331525L, 332110L, 332110L, 263700L, 263701L, 100196L)), .Names = c("Gift_ID", 
"Gift_Date", "Gift_Amount", "Donor_ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-49L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Accomplishing your goal involves chaining many operations (e.g. aggregating by donor/year, filtering by gift > $100, etc.). The `dplyr` package has nice facilities for doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

# gifts defined in question

gifts %>%
  mutate(
    gift_date = as.Date(str_sub(Gift_Date, end = -6), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
    gift_year = year(gift_date) 
  ) %>%   
  group_by(Donor_ID, gift_year) %>% 
  summarise(year_total = sum(Gift_Amount)) %>%
  filter(year_total >= 100) %>% 
  group_by(Donor_ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    jump = !(gift_year == lag(gift_year) + 1 | row_number() == 1),
    donor_seq = cumsum(jump) + 1,
    rle = rep(rle(donor_seq)$lengths, rle(donor_seq)$lengths)
  ) %>%
  filter(rle >= 5) %>% 
  distinct(Donor_ID)
```

Comment: Perhaps use `rle` for run lengths?  E.g. `filter(year_gift >= 100) %>% group_by(bio_id) %>% mutate(diff = gift_year - lag(gift_year), rle = rep( rle(diff)$lengths, rle(diff)$lengths)) %>% filter(rle >= 5) %>% distinct(bio_id)`

Comment: When I try to run either of these, I get this error:
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Something to do with the source being CSV?  I don't know what it means.

Comment: gift_year = year(gifts["Gf_Date"]) causes that error... I think its because the gift date is stored as mm/dd/yyyy instead of the better yyyy/mm/dd.  Is there a way to re-format these?

Comment: @nacnudus - Nice suggestion with rle(). I'll modify my answer to use this.

Comment: @ABvsPred - Please make your question reproducible by supplying dput(gifts)

Comment: There's 11k+ rows of information, so running dput(gifts) runs out of space in the console and only gives the last column's last few thousand data points and then a summary of the dataset.

Comment: Please see addition to question, which includes dput for some of the data and the R-script with associated error message.

Answer (score 1):

Without an actual sample dataset to work with, I can't tell you how to extract the dates, but let's assume you have one column with donorID and another with the gift date.  Then, loop over donorID values (or split your dataset using one tool or another) and use one of my own little functions `seqle`, available in the `cgwtools` package at [github.com/cellocgw](https://github.com/cellocgw/cgwtools_rev2)github.com/cellocgw .  Assuming you are certain that donors never give twice in the same year, all you have to do is find an existence of a sequence longer than `4` .

example made up follows. For simplicity I've used years 1 thru 14 or so and 3 donors.

```
 donmat
      donor   donyear
 [1,] "bob"   "1"    
 [2,] "carol" "1"    
 [3,] "alice" "1"    
 [4,] "bob"   "2"    
 [5,] "carol" "2"    
 [6,] "alice" "3"    
 [7,] "bob"   "3"    
 [8,] "carol" "3"    
 [9,] "alice" "4"    
[10,] "bob"   "5"    
[11,] "carol" "4"    
[12,] "alice" "5"    
[13,] "bob"   "6"    
[14,] "carol" "5"    
[15,] "alice" "7"    
[16,] "bob"   "8"    
[17,] "carol" "7"    
[18,] "alice" "8"    
[19,] "bob"   "9"    
[20,] "carol" "8"    
[21,] "alice" "9"    
[22,] "bob"   "12"   
[23,] "carol" "9"    
[24,] "alice" "11"   
[25,] "bob"   "13"   
[26,] "carol" "9"    
[27,] "alice" "12"   
[28,] "bob"   "14"   
[29,] "carol" "10"   
[30,] "alice" "13"   
Rgames> donlen <- list()
Rgames> for(j in unique(donmat[,'donor'])) donlen[[j]] <- seqle(donmat[donmat[,'donor']==j,2])
Rgames> donlen
$bob
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 3 2 2 3
  values : num [1:4] 1 5 8 12

$carol
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 5 3 2
  values : num [1:3] 1 7 9

$alice
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 1 3 3 3
  values : num [1:4] 1 3 7 11
```

So by looking at the lengths, we see "carol" has a five-year sequence.  You'll probably want to use `lubridate` to extract the year-value from your date strings.